# Format file name with Rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog

I need to format the name of files that rsyslog will create:

Right now, in /etc/rsyslog.d/51-loggingdriver.conf I have:

```
$template DockerLogs,"/var/log/docker/%HOSTNAME%_%FROMHOST-IP%_%PROGRAMMENAME%_syslog.log"
```

But it appears that programmename gives me something like:

```
gitlab_gitlab.1.2rr19xz43unto19ba1sih7jqg_syslog.log
gitlab_gitlab.1.aw2xvfp77i68i2c87szy5n8g9_syslog.log
gitlab_gitlab.1.ig5hk4j3i5x8i6hi07ebqotln_syslog.log
```

so it gives me several file for the same app, but I would like just one file.
(the random suffix is due to using Docker Swarm Services)

I would like to have this field equals to: `gitlab_gitlab`, or even better, just 'gitlab'

Is it posible? How should I do it ? Is there any way to do a substring ???

Answer (score 0):

You can do many things with the [property replacer](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/property_replacer.html), including taking a substring of fixed size, or more powerfully matching a regular expression. For example,

```
%programmename:R,ERE,1,FIELD:([^_.]+).*--end%
```

instead of `%PROGRAMMENAME%` in your template will stop after the first `_` or `.` character. The `R` means use a regexp, of extended syntax `ERE`, keep the first capture group 1, and if no match use the original FIELD value. The regexp pattern has a capture group `()` which matches any characters but the two mentioned earler `[^_.]+`. The `--end` shows the end of the `R` syntax.